# Formerly functional function suddenly doesn't work without code difference, throws object not found error from passed argument

Tags: r, object

I have a very odd problem. I designed a function a while back that has arguments defined as follows:

```
 elisa<-function(
    file="data.csv",
    Out=paste("Elisa Analysis",Sys.time(),".xlsx"),
    wd="~/Desktop",
    out.folder=wd,
    Rep=2,
    standards=c(1,2),
    orient="horizontal")
    {
```

As you can see above, wd is defaulted to the value of the desktop, and out.folder is defaulted to the value of wd. This is so that users can specify where an output excel document goes separately from where the working directory is, but the default is that they are the same. What is weird is that I have used this function for a while, and I have several users who use this exact code (I installed it on their CPUs, and so I know that it is the exact same), and it works fine for them, but suddenly on my computer it is not working. It gives the following error when I run the function.

```
Error in setwd(out.folder) : object 'wd' not found
```

This is odd for a number of reasons. The first is that if I remove the functional enclosure and run the exact same code "naked," the code works just fine. The object wd is definitely still present by the time it gets to the line of code being referenced, which is simply just

```
setwd(out.folder)
```

Moreover, out.folder has the same definition as wd. What is even weirder is that if you read the error code, it doesn't say that out.folder is not defined or the object isn't found. It says that the other object, wd, is not found, which is odd because out.folder should have just been set to the value

```
"~/Desktop"
```

I am at a loss. A line of code early in the function uses wd just fine, but the error occurs hundreds of lines farther down at the line of code specified. If I remove it, everything functions fine, and if I run the function without the functional enclosure, everything functions fine.

Anybody have any clue what is going on?

Sample (only lines involved since the full code is so large it won't let me post it here)

```
elisa<-function(
file="data.csv",
Out=paste("Elisa Analysis",Sys.time(),".xlsx"),
wd="~/Desktop",
out.folder=wd,
Rep=2,
standards=c(1,2),
orient="horizontal")
{
setwd(wd)
setwd(out.folder)
setwd(wd)
}
```

Comment: That's not complete code (no function body). There's no way we can debug it.

Comment: The full code is fairly large and probably won't make sense without also providing an example file to run, so I don't think a full debug makes much sense. What I am asking is whether or not anyone can think of a reason that a function that had formerly been working would suddenly throw out this kind of nonsensical error

Comment: If you don't want to accept advice, then you need to be doing your own debugging with `traceback` and `browser`.

Comment: That's a logical fallacy and is a rather aggressive one at that. I don't think equating my expression of a reservation about overcomplicating the issue to being impervious to good advise is a mature thought. Also, I already told you what code is causing the issue. What I am looking for is some sort of familiarity from the community with the particular error pattern, i.e. code was working fine, was not changed, then suddenly was not working. Perhaps an update in R causes this behavior? I can tell you that the code is correct. I have run it over and over and over. Nothing is different.

Comment: There, I tried to add the full code. It won't let me without deleting most of my post for some reason. See a sample instead

Comment: After I suggested you were committing yourself to the do-your-own-debugging route, you then later  added a sample function body. I don't see how that is "aggressive". You don't know how many times I have read people on SO claiming that "nothing in their code had changed" only to later admit that ... yes... well ... maybe there was a small change.

Comment: It's your tone, bud. If you don't understand how jumping to the conclusion that I won't take advise isn't striking an aggressive tone, then I can't do anything for ya. Also, see below. It wasn't any omitted code

Comment: If you post a function without a body, then it is not complete code. It cannot be run. It cannot be tested. If you had followed  advice of the SO help center and posted code .... code that would run ... that would demonstrate the error then you would probably have gotten better advice. There's no "tone" in saying that posting just an error message without code that can reproduce it is "incomplete". Just facts.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way around it. This is really interesting. If you state the argument explicitly the same way as the default argument, the function won't work. In other words,

```
elisa(...,out.folder=wd)
```

will throw an error even though it is the default argument format. If you omit it when doing the function call, the function works, or if you give it the same value as wd without going through wd as an intermediary, it works. In other words,

```
elisa(...,wd="~/Desktop",out.folder="~/Desktop",...)
```

and

```
elisa(...,wd="~/Desktop",...)
```

both work. You just can't do

```
elisa(...,wd="~/Desktop",out.folder=wd,...)
```

even though the definition of the function arguments is

```
elisa<-function(
file="data.csv",
Out=paste("Elisa Analysis",Sys.time(),".xlsx"),
wd="~/Desktop",
out.folder=wd,
Rep=2,
standards=c(1,2),
orient="horizontal")
```

It makes no sense, but that's the way around it.

Comment: Arguments you pass in to a function are evaluated in the parent environment, not the environment within the function. Otherwise if you had `x = 47` and passed `x` in as an argument to a function, if that function used `x` as a variable things might get mixed up. This way everything is safe.

Comment: So when I define out.folder in terms of wd, I have to have it defined outside of the function to reference the object even though it works as a default? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Let's not use the word "define" for this, it's not quite right. You can assign things, and you can pass things as arguments to functions. Things you pass as arguments must exist in the parent environment. You cannot reference names of other function arguments when passing an argument to a function. But you can reference anything you've assigned in the global environment.

Comment: A function, in its definition, is free to reference other arguments even as defaults. This is part of the function definition and is fine.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I believe I understand why the result seemed so contradictory now